# Dump the container configuration in StructureMap

Tags: .net, structuremap

I have a ever growing project using StructureMap as the IOC container. I am trying to reduce the amount of code in the StructureMap registries by using the auto-registration with Scan(). As I make changes is there an easy way to dump the current container to the console so i can see if the changes have done what I expected?

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Don't know how I missed that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From memory I think this will do it:

```
ObjectFactory.WhatDoIHave
```